# openShot installation Error-archLinux

Tags: installation, package, archlinux

I wanna install openShot video editor for my arch-Linux but getting following error. Please, someone, help me out.

pastebinLink: https://pastebin.com/sDEEVJNk

```html
<iframe src="https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/sDEEVJNk" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I removed `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/` folder. After that, I have installed openShot successfully.

After that, I installed `zmq`.

```
$ sudo pip install zmq
```